# I cant get an Input value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So i am trying to get the value of an input tag with javascript and show it on the console but it doesnot work at all. this is my code, what am i missing here?

```
const userTextValue = document.getElementById('user-text').value;


const show = () => {
  console.log(userTextValue);
}

const submit = document.getElementById('submit');

submit.addEventListener('click', show);
```

Comment: Does the element with id "user-text" exist? Does the element with id "submit" exist? Does this run before the user has entered something? Does running this code summon badgers in the next room? What exactly doesn't work here?

Comment: Most likely you're attaching a click event to the submitter element, and the form is submitted (and the page is reloaded). Set the console to preserve old logs, then you'll see the logged value. That's probably an empty string, though, you've to read the value in the event handler, it's just a string, it's not linked to the value of the element.

Comment: yes both elements with those ids exist.

Comment: how do i tell the console to preserve old logs and by the way it worked for me before, i just dont know what i did wrong this time :(

Comment: i put the userTextValue declaration inside the event handler, still same result.

Comment: How to set options of the DevTools depends on the used browser. In Firefox there's Console Settings icon (a small gear), click it and tick "Persist logs", in Chromium tools there's a similar Settings icon, in the Network section check Preseve log.

Answer (score 3):

Access the input value when you click on show button, so that you get the updated value entered by user.

```js
const show = () => {
  const userTextValue = document.getElementById('user-text').value;
  console.log(userTextValue);
}

const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener('click', show);
```

```html
<div>
<input id="user-text" />
<button id="submit">Show</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you submit the page refresh by default to prevent that you can do it like this

```
const show = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(userTextValue);
}
```

Comment: @Falconcode Yup, except the form is not submitted to your server (not sure if that even should, though).

Comment: i am just experimenting for now, i am taking a React course so just wanted to know how some things worked.

Comment: hey it is me again, i have noticed the console holds on to the old  values and i want to only show the the input value i submitted on the console. any idea, how can i solve that?